# Не работает IntelliSense в javascript коде

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Привет всем. Такая проблема. Проект ASP.NET MVC, VS 2015 Community.

Вдруг перестал работать IntelliSense, причем только для javascript кода, как в отдельных js-файлах, так и секциях cshtml. 

Авто завершение для cshtml, css, cs кода работает. Перезапуск VS не помогает, выгрузка/загрузка решения в обозревателе проекта не помогает, перезагрузка компа не помогает.

Открываю другое решение ASP MVC – IntellySense работает как надо. Развернул проект на другой машине – то же самое, IntellySense работает везде кроме javascript кода.

Подозреваю что что-то поломалось в самом решении. Сравнивал параметры проектов – все вроде одинаково, но в одном IntellySense работает, а в другом нет. 

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным. Пожалуйста помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. 
Внимательно изучая структуру проекта в обозревателе решения, обнаружил в папке Script файлы jquery-3.1.1.slim.js, jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js, jquery-3.1.1.slim.map. Открыл другой проект, где была версия jquery-1.10.2 – таких файлов там не было. Взял и удалил эти файлы из проекта, и о чудо – IntelliSense в javascript коде ЗАРАБОТАЛ. Запустил проект, все вроде работает нормально. Глянул в обозреватель решения, а эти файлы там опять появились, только помечены желтыми воск. значками. В общем, через NuGet понизил версию jquery до 2.2.4 и все стало норм.